# How to set subdomains whit ip using nginx

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, subdomain

Can subdomains be used with ip on Nginx for testing, like teste.x.x.x.x
I did this but does not work.

server_name teste.x.x.x.x teste2.x.x.x.x  ;

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that is not possible, since an IP address is an entity by itself, and subdomains are a feature of DNS's structure or hierarchy.

However, for testing purposes, you could edit you `/etc/hosts` file, adding the following:

```
x.x.x.x teste.yourdomain.com
y.y.y.y teste2.yourdomain.com
```

and this way, accessing `teste.yourdomain.com` in your browser, would redirect your requests to `x.x.x.x`